# The MKCoordinateRegion always locked on center Coordinates 0,0?

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit

This is a little strange, but I have been trying to find a solution for 2 days straight, to set the map region but nothing seems to work 
Here is my code :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
//[self step1locationupdate];
Maplocation.showsUserLocation=YES;

MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;

    mapRegion.center.longitude=self.currentProduct.shop.longcoordinate;
mapRegion.center.latitude=self.currentProduct.shop.latcoordinate;

NSLog(@"The USer Location are :%f",mapRegion.center.latitude);

mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta= 2;
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta= 2;

[Maplocation setRegion:mapRegion animated:YES];
NSLog(@"The USer Location are :%f %f",Maplocation.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,Maplocation.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

The NSLog for malocation.userlocation.coordinate are always 0 when it starts.
The same code I have added it into the viewDidLoad part & also there was no difference

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have saved the above method in a (void) method , then I have fired it after 5 Sec from viewWillAppear method.

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self performSelector:@selector(updatecurrentLocation) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
    -(void)updatecurrentLocation{

    Maplocation.showsUserLocation=YES;
    MKCoordinateRegion mapregion;
    mapregion.center=Maplocation.userLocation.coordinate;
    mapregion.span.latitudeDelta = 2;
    mapregion.span.longitudeDelta = 2;
    [Maplocation setRegion:mapregion animated: YES];
}
```

That is it folks :)

Comment: You've also switched from using `self.currentProduct.shop.longcoordinate` to `Maplocation.userLocation.coordinate` to create the region to give to `Maplocation`. To me that suggests your `curenntProduct.shop.longcoordinate` has not been set. The 5 second delay is an oddity and while it may work in your test case it might take longer for the userLocation to be ready on other devices where they don't have good GPS reception. You'd be better off adding a method from the MKMapViewDelegate protocol like didUpdateUserLocation which will be called once the location is ready.

Comment: Well i Tried Earlier the DidUpdateUserLocation , but it was never called , That's Why i came up with this delay to fire the Location with Timer , as nothing is fired on its own

Comment: didUpdateUserLocation will be called if you've set up your delegates correctly and told the location manager to find your location. If you assume every device this app runs on will have a location 5 seconds after the view appears it's bound to behave badly for some users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize your MKCoordinateRegion before you start using it. Something like 'MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = MKMakeRegionWithCoordinates(......'

Comment: Well I have Tried it but i have the same Result , The Weird Part that i have tried the same Code in a new ViewController & it worked Perfectly .The only Difference is that the First which is not Working has the Map inside a Custom UITableViewCell , The Second is inside a normal UIViewController